# ssh over VPN to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, l2tp

I have remote server(ubuntu server). I access remote server by ssh as `ssh root@IP_OF_SERVER`, then I have setup a webapp running in server and access it by `IP_OF_SERVER:80`. Every thing is working fine. Now I want to access server only over `VPN` means ssh over vpn connection. Here is my setup

> local system  <----> Mikrotik router <---------internet-------> remote server(ubuntu)

I have installed [IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_12.04](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_12.04.html) in remote server.

In mikrotik router I have setup `L2TP client` now I can able to connect to `VPN` server of ubuntu from Mikrotik router. I can also able to ping remote server, but I can't do ssh to remote server when `VPN` is connected and also can't get webapp(`IP_OF_SERVER:80`) in my local system. what would be the problem? Outside `VPN`, remote server is accessible over ssh but not inside `VPN`.
My local system is have `ubuntu desktop`.

**Update:**
**After mikrotik router connected to `VPN` server of Remote server**. Result of `telnet`:

```
niren@slash:~$ telnet SERVER_IP 443
Trying SERVER_IP...
Connected to SERVER_IP.
Escape character is '^]'.

niren@slash:~$ telnet SERVER_IP 22
Trying SERVER_IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

niren@slash:~$ telnet SERVER_IP 80
Trying SERVER_IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Result of `PING`:

```
niren@slash:~$ ping SERVER_IP
PING SERVER_IP (SERVER_IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from SERVER_IP: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.389 ms
64 bytes from SERVER_IP: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.280 ms
64 bytes from SERVER_IP: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.246 ms
```

Result of `SSH`:

```
niren@slash:~$ ssh root@SERVER_IP
ssh: connect to host SERVER_IP port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: firewall maybe?

Comment: I turned off firewall and tried but no luck

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have OPENSSH installed on both machines for SSHing. Use `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` for the one you want to SSH into and `sudo apt-get install openssh-client` for the one you want to SSH from.

Comment: OP stated that he has working SSH connection before VPN implemented.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I got a bit confused by his wording. Someone please remove my answer then.